# Responsive texto web con etiqueta h1

Tags: css, responsive, mediaqueries

uso html y css. Estoy intentanto hacer responsive a la etiqueta H1 para que se vea el texto adecuado en el móvil pero no lo consigo). Necesito que el texto se vea más pequeño y que haya margen con el nav-bar (en web está perfecto), como indico más abajo, he creado @mediapara etiqueta h1, en producción aparece si revisoel código en web, pero una vez subido al vps, ya no aparece. Gracias de antemano

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) .col-lg-7 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  max-width: 58.333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .col-md-12 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) .col-sm-1 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  max-width: 8.333333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-12 col-lg-7">
  <div class="welcome-content mt-sm-100">
    <h1 class="h1-responsive wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s" style="color: white; width: 450px; visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.4s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">Seguimiento de pedidos en tiempo real</h1>
    <div class="slider-btn mt-30">
    </div>
```

---

Cuanto tengo abierto el editor me salen estos medias pero cuando subo la web al vps y miro el código no aparece:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px)
h1 {
   font-size: 2.6rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px)
h1 {
   font-size: 2.3rem;
}
@media (min-width: 600px)
h1 {
   font-size: 0.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 400px)
h1 {
   font-size: 0.5rem;
```

Comment: ¿Agregaste la `meta` tag para el viewport? Algo cómo así: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: tengo esto, initial-scale=1 no;

´´´
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
´´´

Comment: @ArielMontes me cambió el tamaño pero muy pequeño en el móvil. ¿Cómo puedo adaptarlo a lo que necesito?

¿Cómo puedo dar margen entre el texto y el navbar solo en versión móvil?

Comment: @ArielMontes probé a modificar el número de font y para que se vea bien, aparece enorme en el pc.

Respecto a ´´´
mt-5 mt-md0
´´
´tampoco me ha funcionado

Comment: @ArielMontes
mañana le mando, ya no me da tiempo y estoy en un pc muy pequeño para ello

Comment: @ArielMontes Buenas tardes, he conseguido arreglar algo, el problema es que chrome no me detecta los media queries que he puesto, ¿cual debe ser la causa?

Comment: @ArielMontes sí, acabo de probarlo y todo perfecto, la web la bajé de referencia y he ido modificándola, de modo que hay alguno queries que están, pero los que he modificado (simplemente añadido pautas) no aparecen

Comment: @ArielMontes se acaban de corregir los cambios, no se por qué Google tarda en actualizar la web un rato, normalmente los cambios son inmediatos.
Se puede hacer un "p style" concreto un @media? perdón por mi desconocimiento pero voy aprendiendo sobre la marcha

Comment: me refería si a X  p style se le puede aplicar un @media.  Tengo varios p style pero solo quiero aplicarlo a uno, si no ya no me complico más, con lo que he conseguido me siento satisfecha

Comment: Listo, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda